# Installation Error: installing basemap on windows

Tags: python, installation, matplotlib-basemap

I'm trying to install basemap, and it seems worked fine using,

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```

in anaconda prompt. However when I entered this code on my jupyternotebook,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

it showed an error:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-4fc84cbcc854> in <module>()
  1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 2 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

~\Documents\DataScience\data\lib\site- 
packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py in <module>()
144 
145 # create dictionary that maps epsg codes to Basemap kwargs.
--> 146 epsgf = open(os.path.join(pyproj.pyproj_datadir,'epsg'))
147 epsg_dict={}
148 for line in epsgf:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'epsg'
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like matplotlib tries to access some information that isn't in the same conda package.

According to [this comment](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/420#issuecomment-479725764) on an issue, epsg data is in a package `proj4`, and you have to set environment variable PROJ_LIB so that matplotlib finds it.